# How to make bootstrap navbar work in my Rails movie review application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I included all the files that are needed to run the bootstrap, but the navbar is not working, it looks like normal HTML.

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.4.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 6.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.4'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'
gem 'rails-ujs', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'sassc-rails', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.2'
```

application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

This is the header file that I used for Navbar, _header.html.erb:

```
<nav class="navbar" navbar-default role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
    </button>
    <%= link_to "Movies Reviews", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "New Movie" , new_movie_path, class: "active" %> </li>
      <li> <%= link_to "Account", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
      <% else %>
        <li> <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "active" %></li>
        <li> <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, class: "active" %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <div class="form_group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Moviereview</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg|%>
    <%= content_tag(:div ,msg, class:"alert alert_info")%>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I saw the same question and applied all the answers in that but don't get the proper result. Here is the output I am getting:

[image: see what type of output I am getting]

Comment: Please add the HTML for the result. Don't add "edit" or "update" type tags as we can see what changed. See "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)".

Comment: ```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.1'
```

It seams you have installed the version 3 and the last version of bootstrap is version 4 
The class names are not the same so it's not working correctly

Comment: but I copied the gem from the official site rubygems.org  and it still shows version 3.4 for the bootstrap-sass

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install bootstrap and its required dependencies with from the terminal?

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing bootstrap in Ruby on Rails 6:

```
https://getbootstrap.com/
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem
// Gemfile.rb
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.4.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'

// Console
bundle install
yarn add bootstrap@4.3.1 jquery popper.js

// application.scss
@import "bootstrap";

// config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack")
environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
$: 'jquery',
jQuery: 'jquery',
Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
module.exports = environment

// packs/application.js
import "bootstrap"
```

Source:
https://gist.github.com/yshmarov/758a04798c3400cf125de27659dab43e/#file-gem-bootstrap

Comment: There is no config/webpack/environment.js. I only have config folder and one file in it named manifest.js and also there is not folder like "packs"

Comment: I am using Rails 5.2 in the version 6 I am getting errors with other packages like version mismatch so I had installed this 5.2